# Vuejs - Best way of avoiding mutating of props when three components are interlinked

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, mutation

I know mutating the props isn't a good idea, i want to know best way of using the props in my case. I referred few examples but, did not get the exact way. This question has been raised many of a times, but i think its worth asking.

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
 <first-component :actualValue="apiData.services"></first-component>
```

**FirstComponent.vue**

```
    <second-component :label="Service 1" :valueRend="actualValue.service1"></second-component>
        ...
    <second-component :label="Service 2" :valueRend="actualValue.service2"></second-component>
        ...
     props:{
        actualValue:{type:Object},
     }
```

**SecondComponent.vue**

```
    <label class="label">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="valueRend"
          @change="onChange"
        />
        {{ label }}
     </label>

      ...

      props:{
        valueRend:{type:Object},
        label:{type:String}
      }
      methods:{
        onChange(){
          this.$emit('update-change', this.valueRend)
        }
      }
```

So from the code you can observe that i am actually mutating the props, please let me know effective way of avoiding the mutation of props in my example.

When I try to update my checkbox's value i get props cannot be mutated, so please do tell me how can i solve my problem.

Comment: Mind explaining the intention/expected results?

Comment: When prop passing starts getting complicated, probably a sign it's time for Vuex.

Comment: I am actually trying to update the object, i am using checkbox so once it is changed i am trying to update it. But as lot of codes, i decided to make a new component in ParentComponent then, as the inputs were same and only differ was in label and value i decided to make another new component in SecondComponent, So the FirstComponent is the another component in SecondComponent. Please let me how to bind data in my case or how to avoid mutation